# Rspec uninitialized constant for class nested inside module - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In a Rails project, I have created a new class inside the `lib` directory, this class is namespaced inside a module. When creating a spec file for it, I'm seeing `NameError: uninitialized constant MyNamespace`.

Here is my folder structure

```
app/
...
lib
  my_namespace
    my_new_class.rb
  another_namespace
    another_old_class.rb
spec
  lib
    my_namespace
      my_new_class_spec.rb
    another_namespace
      another_old_class_spec.rb
```

Here the (abbreviated) contents of:
`lib/my_namespace/my_new_class.rb`

```rb
module MyNamespace
  class MyNewClass
  end
end
```

`spec/lib/my_namespace/my_new_class_spec.rb`

```rb
RSpec.describe MyNamespace::MyNewClass do
  it "is true"
    expect(true).to eq(true) # irrelevant at this point
  end
end
```

The reason I included `another_old_class_spec.rb` is that its tests run without issue and I can't find anywhere that it's explicitly loaded or required in the test setup (in case that might be a potential issue).

When running the test with `bundle exec rspec spec/lib/my_namespace/my_new_class_spec.rb` or even `bundle exec rspec spec/lib/my_namespace/` I get

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/lib/my_namespace/my_new_class_spec.rb
Failure/Error:
RSpec.describe MyNamespace::MyNewClass do

NameError:
  uninitialized constant MyNamespace
```

Comment: Well, stuff from `lib` directory should be `require`d. Maybe `lib/another_namespace` was required in `application.rb`?

Comment: If you mean `config/application.rb`, then it's not, unfortunately. There's also nothing about this particular file in any environment file (e.g. `config/environments/test.rb`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Georgiy Melnikov implied in his comment, by default the `/lib` directory is not in [autoload paths](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths), so the constant `MyNamespace` is not automatically resolved.

You basically have two options to fix this:

1. explicitly require the file with `require lib/my_namespace/my_new_class` at the top of the spec file
2. add `lib/` to autoload paths (nowadays this is discouraged)

Comment: To Michael's scenario, even though above will resolve the issue. How do you explain "why existing/old classes/namespaces under lib are working just fine"? 

I mean why does the issue happens with only newly created namespaces and files under them, why does it not happen to older ones. Would you be able to explain that please.

Comment: @SukhvirSingh the possibilities are
1) the file is already required/loaded somewhere else.
2) the file is in the autoload paths

For option 1) Michael mentioned that "I can't find anywhere that it's explicitly loaded or required in the test setup". This comment is a bit ambigous - what exactly is meant by "test setup"? For example, if the require expression is somewhere inside the app/ or lib/ code, is that considered part of the "test setup"?

Comment: Cont 1: My recommendation is: run the `another_old_class_spec.rb` file on it's own - if it passes then `another_old_class.rb` is either required in some code that runs before the test (commonly `spec_helper.rb`, `rails_helper.rb`, `config/environments/test.rb`, `application.rb`, initializers etc.) OR it's autoloaded.

If the tests in the file don't pass on their own, but do pass when the whole test suite is ran, then `another_old_class_spec.rb` is probably required by some class in app code (commonly `/app` or `/lib` which _another_ test runs.

Comment: Cont 2: But since the order of tests is (usually) random, this often leads to flaky test; the test passes only if some other test requiring the file is ran first.